# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in React MailChimp Signup Form

Tags: reactjs, mailchimp

Really new to this, I've tried looking at other examples but just not making sense, so any help would be much appreciated! 
What I am trying to do is have a simple text field and submit button that will add the email address to a MailChimp campaign list. So just a simple (in theory) mailing signup list.

I keep getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
onChange:

```
onChange(e) {
14 |    var email = e.target.value
15 |    this.setState= this.setState.bind(this);
16 |    this.setState({email})
17 | }
18 | render() {
```

I've tried binding, am I doing this right?

Comment: To see full code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677995/react-mailing-signup-error?noredirect=1#comment78313592_45677995

Comment: `onChange = (e) => {}` And next time try to search before asking a question.
You need to bind `onChange` and not `setStae`.

Comment: I did, but nothing was making sense.

Comment: Check this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to bind the `setState` function, but `onChange` needs to be bind. And are you initializing the state containing email like ES6 in constructor?

```
this.state = { 
    email : ''
}

//bind onChange(e) ===== in constructor >  like
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

onChange(e) {
    var email = e.target.value;
    this.setState({email} //or try this.setState({email:email});
}
```